# How to check javascript bad word check as a whole?

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is a string list with bad words. I want it to give a warning when there are words in this list. True if it contains, false if it does not.

I wrote a function, but since I used the "includes" method, it perceives the words in the word as swearing. The word is "Albad". It returns true because there is "bad" in the bad word list.

How can I detect profanity when written as a whole? For example, when you write "Al bad", it will be perceived as swearing.

```js
badWordCheck(value: string): boolean {
   var badWords = ["bad","bad1","bad2","bad3"];
   let isInclude = badWords.some(word => value.includes(word));
   return isInclude;
        
}
this.badWordCheck("Albad")
```

Comment: Clbuttic! Are you going to repeat the mistakes of [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem)

Answer (score 1):

You can split `value` by spaces and then check if any of those words are in your `badWords` array.

Simplified example:

```js
const badWords = ["bad", "bad1", "bad2", "bad3"];

function checkBadWord(value) {
  const inputWords = value.split(/\s+/); // Split value by spaces
  return inputWords.some((word) => badWords.includes(word.toLowerCase())); // Check if any words match
}

console.log(checkBadWord('Al bad')); // => true
console.log(checkBadWord('Albad')); // => false
```

This version splits `value` into words and then checks if any of those words exactly match the words in your `badWords` array.